# Environmenal flow in the context of global gridded hydrological analyses

Tags: hydrology, water, environmental-protection

Environmental flow (EF) is a widely used concept in river basin management and river ecology. There are more than 200 methods to estimate the flow that should be left to the rivers to ensure a sustainable resource management, and it is almost impossible to standardize a methodology that could be applied for each stream everywhere in the world.

Although some global exercises have been performed ([IWMI for instance](http://www.iwmi.cgiar.org/resources/models-and-software/environmental-flow-calculators/)), in fact, the EF is extremely site and season specific: it depends on the natural conditions of the river, its hydrological, geo-morphological, and biological features, and its natural ecosystem. That for, the use of specific methodologies makes sense in the management of a specific river basin or a portion of it, but what about global hydrological analyses?

I am setting up a global gridded hydrological analysis and, while accounting for water uses, I would like to set up a threshold under which the water withdrawal is not allowed. I am thinking of using a percentile of the historical modeled monthly time series of discharge spanning a period of about 30 years. This would allow to set the threshold to a value for each month that is a percentile of the historical undisturbed (natural, with no fragmentation or withdrawal) discharge, for each of the grid-cells. Is this an acceptable approximation?